# How to match numeric characters with no white space following

Tags: python, regex

I need to match lines in text document where the line starts with numbers and the numbers are followed by nothing.... I want to include numbers that have `'.'` and `','` separating them.

Currently, I have:

```
p = re.compile('\$?\s?[0-9]+') 

for i, line in enumerate(letter):
   m = p.match(line)
   if s !=None:
      print(m)
      print(line)
```

Which gives me this:

"15,704" and "416" -> this is good, I want this

but also this:

"$40 million...." -> I do not want to match this line or any line where the numbers are followed by words.

I've tried:

```
p = re.compile('\$?\s?[0-9]+[ \t\n\r\f\v]')
```

But it doesn't work. One reason is that it turns out there is no white space after the numbers I'm trying to match.

Appreciate any tips or tricks.

Comment: maybe something like this https://regex101.com/r/6eh7Vg/1

Comment: The tip is the regexp symbol `$`, which matches the end of the line or string. Use it to build a regexp that _must_ match all the way to the end of the string.

Comment: @JoranBeasley big fan of that link. Wanted to highlight for other people looking at this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match **the whole string** with a regex,
you have 2 choices:

- Either call `re.fullmatch(pattern, string)` (note **full** in the function name).
  It tries to match just the **whole** string.
- Or put `$` anchor at the end of your regex and call `re.match(pattern, string)`.
  It tries to find a match **from the start** of the string.

Actually, you could also add `^` at the start of regex and call `re.search(pattern,
string)`, but it would be a very strange combination.

I have also a remark concerning how you specified your conditions, maybe in incomplete
way: You put e.g. `$40 million` string and stated that the **only** reason to reject
it is space and letters after `$40`.

So actually you should have written that you want to match a string:

- Possibly starting with `$`.
- After the `$` there can be a space (maybe, I'm not sure).
- Then there can be a sequence of digits, dots or commas.
- And nothing more.

And one more remark concerning Python literals: Apparently you have forgotten to prepend the pattern with `r`.
If you use *r-string literal*, you do not have to double backslashes inside.

So I think the most natural solution is to call a function devoted just to
match **the whole string** (i.e. `fullmatch`), without adding start / end
anchors and the whole script can be:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'(?:\$\s?)?[\d,.]+')
lines = ["416", "15,704", "$40 million"]
for line in lines:
    if pat.fullmatch(line):
        print(line)
```

Details concerning the regex:

- `(?:` - A non-capturing group.

  - `\$` - Consisting of a `$` char.
  - `\s?` - And optional space.
- `)?` - End of the non-capturing group and `?` stating that **the whole
  group** group is optional.
- `[\d,.]+` - A sequence of digits, commas and dots (note that between `[`
  and `]` the dot represents itself, so no backslash quotation is needed.

If you would like to reject strings like `2...5` or `3.,44` (no consecutive
dots or commas allowed), change the last part of the above regex to:

```
[\d]+(?:[,.]?[\d]+)*
```

Details:

- `[\d]+` - A sequence of digits.
- `(?:` - A non-capturing group.

  - `[,.]` - Either a comma or a dot (**single**).
  - `[\d]+` - Another sequence of digits.
- `)*` - End of the non-capturing group, it may occur several times.

Comment: I don't fully understand why you are putting `(?:\$\s?)` in a group. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: "\$" matches literal dollar (it must be escaped to treat it literally, not as the "End" anchor). "\s" stands for a space, optional because of "?". Actually, instead of "\s" there could be just a space.

Comment: Yes. I understand. Why are you grouping them?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('^[0-9,.]+\s*$')

lines = ["416", "15,704", "$40 million...."]

for line in lines:
    if pattern.match(line):
        print(line)
```

**Output**

```
416
15,704
```

The pattern `^[0-9,.]+\s*$` matches everything that is a digit a `,` or `.`, followed by zero or more spaces. If you want to match only numbers with one `,` or `.` use the following pattern: `'^\d+[,.]?\d+\s*$'`, code:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('^\d+[,.]?\d+\s*$')

lines = ["416", "15,704", "$40 million...."]

for line in lines:
    if pattern.match(line):
        print(line)
```

**Output**

```
416
15,704
```

The pattern `^\d+[,.]?\d+\s*$` matches everything that starts with a group of digits (`\d+`) followed by an optional `,` or `.` (`[,.]?`) followed by a group of digits, with an optional group of spaces `\s*`.

Comment: This is very helpful but I don't understand why you're using `^` before `\d`. Based off your answer, I'm now using this: `b = re.compile(r'\$?\s?[0-9,.]+\s*$')`

Comment: The `^` means the pattern must match at the beginning of the text.

Answer (score 0):

With a little modification to your code:

```
letter = ["15,704", "$40 million"]
p = re.compile('^\d{1,3}([\.,]\d{3})*$') # Numbers separated by commas or points

for i, line in enumerate(letter):
    m = p.match(line)
    if m:
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
15,704
```